# How to write an integer variable to log file with f.write?

Tags: python

This script is a simple while True loop that checks a voltage value and writes a log file. However, I am not able to get the voltage value written in the log.

Simple log files with a text string and date / timestamp work fine but the write fails when I try to use the variable name.

```
ina3221 = SDL_Pi_INA3221.SDL_Pi_INA3221(addr=0x40)

LIPO_BATTERY_CHANNEL = 1

busvoltage1 = ina3221.getBusVoltage_V(LIPO_BATTERY_CHANNEL)

while True:

    if busvoltage1 <= 3.70:

        with open("/<path>/voltagecheck.log", "a") as f:
                f.write("battery voltage below threshold: " + busvoltage1 + "\n")
                f.write("timestamp: " + time.asctime() + "\n")
                f.write("-------------------------------------------" + "\n")
                f.close()
    else:

        time.sleep(3600)
```

I've also tried:

```
with open("/<path>/voltagecheck.log", "a") as f:
        f.write("battery voltage below threshold: " + str(busvoltage1) + "\n")
        f.write("timestamp: " + time.asctime() + "\n")
        f.write("-------------------------------------------" + "\n")
        f.close()
```

Without trying to add the busvoltage1 value to the log, the log is created and the timestamp line works fine.

With the busvoltage1 value, the log is created but nothing is written.

When running this in the terminal, the errors for "str(busvoltage1)" and just the plain "busvoltage1" are:

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

and

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Comment: `v` != `f`. I'm missing something here, why do you use `as v`?

Comment: your code is wrongly indented - please fix it

Comment: This will throw an error that `f` is not defined. Either you have a typo in your question, or you're writing to a completely different file than you think you are. This code cannot behave as you describe.

Comment: `file.write()` only writes strings  - if you want to write floats or ints you need to format them:  `v.write("my "+str(number))` or `v.write( "my {}".format(number))` or `v.write(f"my {number}")` - see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files and [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) and [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [string format mini lang](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

Comment: You must write to `v`, not `f`. Try `v.write("battery voltage below threshold: {}\n".format(busvoltage1))` or `print("battery voltage below threshold: ", busvoltage1, file=v)`.

Comment: Fixed v != f (typo).

Comment: @PatrickArtner thank you, your link helped. I was having trouble sifting through python documentation.

I assigned `v = str(busvoltage1)` then was able to use `f.write(battery voltage below threshold: " + v + "\n")`

Comment: @PatrickArtner Also, I don't see any checkbox to mark the answer as accepted..

Comment: You can not accept comments - only answers. The question is kindof easy to solve so I just commented to get you on the right track to solve it yourself. if you like you can create an answer yourself in the box below and accept it in 2 days - but there are so many "string formatting gone wrong" questions on SO already that I am not sure it will benefit from another one. Maybe copy the links over from my comment for anybody that finds your selfanswer.

Answer (score 0):

The value needs to be formatted as a string before f.write is used.

Added `v = str(busvoltage1)` and then referenced `v` in f.write: `f.write(battery voltage below threshold: " + v + "\n")`

This is referenced in the 5th example of 7.2.1 here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files. Thanks @PatrickArtner